# Javascript - mouseover/out event fires on all sibling elements at the same time

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, getelementsbyclassname

I have four sibling elements with a class of "box". I use the `getElementsByClassName()` with a for loop to iterate over the matching set of elements and use the `addEventListener()` method to bind a `mouseover` event to each element.

**The problem** I am having is when I use `.style.display` in the event handler, and mouse over any of the matching elements, all of the preceding sibling  matching elements change their display values.

If I use a different style method like `.style.backgroundColor` everything works fine. I have googled and youtubed and I can't find a solution. I would appreciate any and all assistance, thank you.

**Code:**

```
function hover(eClass) {
  var elem = document.getElementsByClassName(eClass);
  for (var i=0;i<elem.length;i++) {
    elem[i].addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver);
    elem[i].addEventListener('mouseout', mouseOut);
  }
  function mouseOver() {    
    //this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    this.style.display = 'none';
  }
  function mouseOut() {
    //this.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
  }  
}
hover('box');
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/fmrogers/pen/YqVyZd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your code. It's fine. In fact, ig you try to hover the last (at the bottom) square, only it will disappear. When you hover the top one, it disappears and next one become the top one, so it disappear too, and so on, until all them disappear. This happen too fast and it seams that all squares disappear at once...

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am of course somewhat upset i did not realize this myself. The example was simply a test too see if my hover function would work as intended.

Answer (score 2):

This was funny, and it took a while to see that it's just a practical problem. When you hover over the first box, it is removed, and the next one is redrawn in its place. But then the event fires again on box 2, because *it* is now below the cursor, and so it continues. Of course this happens too fast to see, but it's what's going on. If you really want to remove the element from the browser's draw function, you'll have to figure out something to stop the event firing on the next element, or set opacity: 0.

**Update**

This is sort of ugly, but removing the event listeners and adding them again demonstrates how this *could* work. http://codepen.io/dannyjolie/pen/mPmpqE

```
function mouseOver() {
  //this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
  removeListeners('box');
  this.style.display = 'none';
  setTimeout(function(){
    addListeners('box');
  }, 100);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. The code example was simply a proof of concept and was never intended to be used in that way. I stumbled into the aforementioned problem and when i realized i had no clue what was wrong i came here. Thank you for taking the time to help and have a nice day sir!

Answer (score 1):

`misher` beat me to it, but yes that is what's happening. I put 1 - 4 in the `DIV`s:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="box grey">1</div>
    <div class="box grey">2</div>
    <div class="box grey">3</div>
    <div class="box grey">4</div>
</div>
```

And used the `console` to catch the `innerHTML` of the elements and they vanish, which gave me:

```
1
2
3
4
```

No surprise there, once the `display` is set to `none`, the elements move up as the one you hovered no longer has its CSS in play. You can use `visibility` to keep that from happening, but the `mouseout` event will not trigger on invisible elements.

With a bit of tweaking, you can use the `data` attribute and the `mousemove` event to keep the elements in place; this will only fire once so if the page re-sizes or moves the X and Y values will be off, perhaps a `window.onresize` would fix that, but here's this:

```
function hover(eClass) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName(eClass);
    for (var i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
        elem[i].addEventListener('mouseover', mouseOver);
    }
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
    function mouseOver() {
        var minX = this.offsetLeft;
        var maxX = minX + this.offsetWidth;
        var minY = this.offsetTop;
        var maxY = minY + this.offsetHeight;
        this.setAttribute('data-minx', minX);
        this.setAttribute('data-maxx', maxX);
        this.setAttribute('data-miny', minY);
        this.setAttribute('data-maxy', maxY);
        this.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    function mouseMove(e) {
        e = e || event;
        for(i = 0; i < elem.length; i++) {
            var div = elem[i];
            var minX = div.getAttribute('data-minx');
            var maxX = div.getAttribute('data-maxx');
            var minY = div.getAttribute('data-miny');
            var maxY = div.getAttribute('data-maxy');
            if(e.clientX >= minX && e.clientX <= maxX && e.clientY >= minY && e.clientY <= maxY) {
                // over the Div
            } else {
                div.style.visibility = 'visible';
            }
        }
    }
}

hover('box');
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, misher may have beat you too it, but i appreciate your response. I realise i should have mention that the example code was simply a proof of concept. It was a simple accident that i discovered the problem. Now i am am left feeling somwhat relieved i made no obvious mistakes and yet i also feel i should have figured this out myself. Oh well, lessons were learned. Have a nice day!